# How to change the height of an element in the up direction and have above neighbors react accordingly?

Tags: html, css, layout, height

There is a list of collapsible sections. When a section is opened it needs to move (change height) in the up direction so that the elements above it move and the elements below it don't move. Note that it's acceptable that the above elements go overflow.

`absolute` can't be used because it won't push the elements above it.
Also note that the height of the content of a section when open is dynamic and not known.

By default this works when the content of a section is set to display none when the sections is closed and unset when it is open but it's moving the sections below it.

Any other solution to reverting the direction ?

Tried setting the position to `absolute` when display the content of the section to be opened but it's not a solution.

The below snippet is just for reference. The real application is in react but the functionalities are the same.

**Opening the middle section should move the first section and not the last**

```js
const allCollapsibleSections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="collapsible-section"]')

const setIsOpenFunctions = [];

allCollapsibleSections.forEach((collapsibleSection, index) => {
  const openCloseButton = collapsibleSection.querySelector('button');
  const section = collapsibleSection.querySelector('section');
  let open = section.getAttribute('open') || false;
  
  const renderSection = ()=>{
    if(open){
      section.style.display = 'unset';
      return;
    }
    section.style.display = 'none';
  }
  const toggleIsOpen = () => {
    open = !open;
    renderSection();
  }
  
  renderSection();
  
  setIsOpenFunctions[index] = toggleIsOpen;
  openCloseButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    setIsOpenFunctions[index]();
  });
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a XY problem and the attempted solution is not the only solution to the problem.

So a solution is rather than aiming at moving the elements above, the parent element should have a max-height and be scrollable and when a section is opened, just scroll to that section.

```js
const allCollapsibleSections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="collapsible-section"]')

const setIsOpenFunctions = [];

allCollapsibleSections.forEach((collapsibleSection, index) => {
  const openCloseButton = collapsibleSection.querySelector('button');
  const section = collapsibleSection.querySelector('section');
  let open = section.getAttribute('open') || false;
  
  const renderSection = ()=>{
    if(open){
      section.style.display = 'unset';
      section.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "end",
        inline: "nearest",
      });
      return;
    }
    section.style.display = 'none';
  }
  const toggleIsOpen = () => {
    open = !open;
    renderSection();
  }
  
  renderSection();
  
  setIsOpenFunctions[index] = toggleIsOpen;
  openCloseButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    setIsOpenFunctions[index]();
  });
})
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 80px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"  data-js="collapsible-section">
    <button>Open/Close</button>
    <section style="background: yellow; height: 50px">
      This is a section
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```